# Removing HTML from Pidgin conversations

Tags: windows, plugins, html, pidgin, office-communicator-2007

I'm using Pidgin 2.5.5 with SIPE for talking to MS Communicator user at work. 
The MS Communicator was just now upgraded and I'm seeing HTML markup with messages.

Are there any plugins to interpret HTML and apply the styles or parse it out ?

Thanks
-G

EDIT1: I'm running this on Windows
EDIT2: my convos look like
person@address (time) no

Comment: Are you talking about live during a conversation or in logs?

Comment: during conversations

Comment: Upgrading Pidgin would be a good idea, too.

Comment: upgraded - didn't help

Comment: Oops, I think I missed the point in my answer. For clarification, did you mean you've got bold text in your IMs, or you have raw <b></b> tags in your IMs? (I assumed the former; the other answers assumed the latter.)

Comment: I'm getting html tags in the IM

Answer (score 2):

**edit** I had assumed that George wanted to get rid of formatting in IMs, transforming "*Hello* World" to "Hello World" but I had misunderstood. The issue is getting rid of the HTML when the IM is "<i>Hello</i> World." I would remove my answer, but I'm concerned that someone else will misunderstand it too, so I thought I'd try to help explain.

Tools > Preferences > Conversations has an option to display your current IMs in plain text. Uncheck the option "Show formatting on incoming messages."

If you want to make your logged IMs consistent with this, go to the Logging tab and choose "Plain text" for the log format.

I just confirmed these options for Pidgin 2.5.6 on Windows, but I think they're pretty consistently available.

Comment: this did not help

Answer (score 1):

Can't you write [perl one liners for pidgin](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Scripting%20and%20Plugins#HowdoIusePerlscriptswithPidginFinch) that do filtering? If so write one with a regex like `s/<.*?>//g` or get fancy with a [module for html stripping](http://search.cpan.org/~kilinrax/HTML-Strip-1.06/Strip.pm).

Comment: requires installing ActivePerl. trying it out now

Answer (score 1):

Could DeWYSIWYGification Plugin help? I'm not sure but give it a shot.

Answer (score -1):

set up a SIM module for pidgin - it strips html-tags for broken clients like sim-client.
you should set the "problem user" as SIM-user, by right-clicking on him. it works.